# Why my loop breaks when I start looping inside first loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I try to loop inside loop and when starts second loop, first stops instantly. I need to check endless if RELE1 is True and I need to print for example 'alarm' only once, because of that I loop second time to check is alarm 0 or 1. Here is my code:

```
while True: 
           if (GPIO.input(RELE1) == True):
                print('3.3')
                GPIO.setup(RELE360, GPIO.OUT)

                alarm = 0
                while 1:
                    if (GPIO.input(RELE0) == True):
                        alarm += 1
                        if(alarm == 1 ):
                            print('alarm')
                    else:
                        alarm = 0

           else:
                print('0')
                GPIO.setup(RELE360, GPIO.IN)
                sleep(1);
```

Comment: Please add more details regarding what you mean by *"first stops instantly"*

Comment: The inner loop never ends. You need to `break` out of it at some point.

Comment: You have two infinite loops.  Presumably the outer one is desired, but you will never iterate on the outer loop because you get stuck in the inner one (`while 1:`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. This will never terminate:

```
while True: 
           if (GPIO.input(RELE1) == True):
                print('3.3')
                GPIO.setup(RELE360, GPIO.OUT)

                alarm = 0
                while 1:
                    if (GPIO.input(RELE0) == True):
                        alarm += 1
                        if(alarm == 1 ):
                            print('alarm')
                    else:
                        alarm = 0
                    # -- you will never escape this loop! --

           else:
                print('0')
                GPIO.setup(RELE360, GPIO.IN)
                sleep(1);
```

You can either just remove the loop, or `break` to escape it.

```
while True:
    if some_condition:
        break # this will exit the loop
```

Alternatively, you can just roll your second loop into the first; from looking at your code, it seems like you could do this:

```
alarm = 0
while True: 
           if (GPIO.input(RELE1) == True):
                print('3.3')
                GPIO.setup(RELE360, GPIO.OUT)

                if (GPIO.input(RELE0) == True):
                    alarm += 1
                    if(alarm == 1 ):
                        print('alarm')    
           else:
                print('0')
                GPIO.setup(RELE360, GPIO.IN)
                sleep(1);
```

Comment: I need print 'alarm' only once, but if I do your way it prints always with 3.3 print

Comment: fixed @PavelKaljunen

Comment: but you don't set alarm to 0 and it is shown every second. if(alarm == 1 ):
                        print('alarm')

Comment: if alarm is set to zero in the loop, then it'll print every second; this will only print the first time the RELE0 if statement is true

Comment: RELE0 stay on for a certain time and because of this alarm is printed multiple time

Comment: Ok, it is worked when I added else: alarm = 0 sleep(1); Thank you